# Prove $\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}}+\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}}<2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inequality

Prove that $\forall n \geq 2, n \in \mathbb{N}$ $$E=\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}}+\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}}<2$$

My try:
Since $\forall n \geq 2$ $$0<\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}<1$$
Let $$\cos \theta=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{n}, \theta \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Using $$\begin{aligned}
&1+\cos \theta=2 \cos ^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\
&1-\cos \theta=2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
We get
$$E=2^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(\left(\cos ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{1 / n}+\left(\sin ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{1 / n}\right)$$

Any help from here?

Comment: For any $x\in(-1,1),$ estimate $\sqrt[n]{1+x}$ with power series. Ignore the $\frac{\sqrt[n]n}n$ specific, first.

Comment: Side note: if the inequality $$ \frac {a+b} 2 \leqslant \left(\frac {a^n + b^n}2\right)^{1/n} $$ for $a, b \geqslant 0$ and integers $n\geqslant 1$ is allowed to use, then the inequality in the OP is obvious.

Comment: @Ekaveera: I have tried to answer your question. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 6):

A possible approach: $f(x) = (1+x)^{1/n}$ is strictly concave on $(-1, \infty)$, so that
$$
 f(x) < f(0) + x f'(0) = 1 + \frac xn
$$
for $x > -1, x \ne 0$. (*Remark:* This is one case of [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).)

With $x_n = \sqrt[n]{n} \in (0, 1)$ it follows that
$$
E = \sqrt[n]{1+x_n}+\sqrt[n]{1-x_n} ) = f(x_n) + f(-x_n) < 2 \, .
$$